# Adding value with existing value rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a column `price` with value `10`(may differ) and i need to add value `5`(may differ) to the existing value `10` which is the good way to update this in rails.

Am using following rails query to find by customer_id

`customer_id=25`

`refund_update = Refund.find_by customer_id: customer_id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use several ways to update the value:

with validation:

```
refund_update.increment('price', 5)
```

or

```
refund_update.update_attributes({'price': refund_update.price+5})
```

without validation:

```
refund_update.increment!('price',5)
```

or

```
refund_update.update_attribute('price', refund_update.price+5)
```